# Read Dara from firebase android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHQTG.jpg)
See the picture for my database style.
I cannot read and match and passwords against a username, I am sharing my code here.

```
public void onClickLogInAdmin(View view)
    {
//        //PRE-DEFINED ADMIN PROFILES\
        // Read from the database
        ref=ref.child("AdminCredentials");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String password = (String) snapshot.child("f190191").child("password").getValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}

        });

    }
```

Comment: So you need to check if the key is equal the to he child (password) value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void onClickLogInAdmin(View view)
{
    // PRE-DEFINED ADMIN PROFILES
    // Read from the database
    ref=ref.child("AdminCredentials");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(snapshot.getKey().equals("f190191")) {
                    String password = (String) snapshot.child("password").getValue();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```